# How to make a function wait for 4 seconds before returning?

Tags: javascript

Need to make a function **wait** for 4 seconds before returning a string, but not having any luck. Basically this is what I'm trying to do:

```
function myFunction(){
 var str = '';
// DO SOMEHITNG HERE so when it's done the finally return "I'm done"

 return "I'm done";
}
```

This is what I currently have (What am I missing), but I'm also down for any other way to do this. Thanks in advance!

```
function myFunction(){
 var counter = 0;
 var execute =  setInterval(print,  1000);

 function print(){
    document.write("Counting" + counter + "<br/>");
    ++counter;

    if(counter < 5){
        clearInterval(execute);
         str = "I'm done";
    }
 }

  return str; // Here I want to return "I'm done"
}
```

Comment: Try setTimeout?

Comment: Don’t. Never block the JavaScript thread. Why do you want to pause script execution?

Comment: @Dai any other idea or solution to accomplish this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep

Comment: @Dai because inside the print function I actually have a ajax call and need to wait for it to finish executing and get a value from there, then assign the value to my str variable, so then finally return the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)

Comment: @progx if you have async operations to perform, then you can make use of Promises or simply callbacks

Comment: @progx When working with ajax calls use their callbacks or wrap them in promises

Comment: @progx: you don't have to wait to get values, it's a terrible idea. Instead, learn how to [embrace asynchronicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: Can anyone provide an example please? I already looked into callbacks for 2 days but not getting this to work. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @NickParsons they use callbacks. Basically a function that will collect your response (I get that), but how do you make myFunction return that response? Can you please provide a example/solution? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @progx they also use other methods such as using a promise with `async/await`, here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/L1mu2x76/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't delay the return of a function like you want, but you can return a Promise. For situations like that you need to use sime king of assynchronous function:

```
function myFunction() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("I'm done");
    }, 5000)
  }
}

// Now when you use your function, you need to get the results from a then method:

let someVariable;

myFunction().then(function(output) {
  console.log(output); // I'm done
  someVariable = output;
}

console.log(someVariable); // undefined
```

Keep in mind that asynchronous functions will be always assynchronous. That's why the last console log will output `undefined`.

Comment: But I need to make myFunction return "I'm done". Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: You just can't. Can you exemplify your use case for your function?

Comment: To delay the function like you want you will need to do a dump while, but this would crash your browser.

Comment: Yes let me explain. I have this super Class that has a function called myFunction and I have this child class that extends the super class. Long story short I'm overriding the myFunction from my child class and I need to make this myFunction return a message (coming from an ajax call) and I need to make myFunction return that value. Does that make sense?

Comment: Make sense, but's impossible to do what you want this way. You need to check who use the `myFunction` output and put all logic depending of it output inside some callback function (like the promise `.then() in my answer).

Comment: Keep in mind that your function returns values immediately, while the ajax answer returns answers asynchronously. Everything after some async behavior must be async, even if you need to put a timeout to check for changes every second.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. Thanks for your help. Marking it as the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

In the comments section i read that your using a AJAX and waiting for the response. So you can basically use the below.

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     // DO THE REQUIRED HERE AFTER RESPONSE
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
and [WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

```js
function sleep(seconds) {
  return new Promise(result => setTimeout(result, seconds * 1000))
}

async function myFunction() {
  // DO SOMEHITNG HERE so when it's done the finally return "I'm done"
  await sleep(4) // <-- 4 seconds
  return `I'm done`
}

async function asyncCall() {
  let str = ''
  console.log('str:', str) // <-- empty here

  str = await myFunction()
  console.log('str:', str) // <-- I\'m done
}

asyncCall()
```

Comment: In this case your function returns the string `'I\'m done'`... I will improve the example

Comment: Can you try not use the arrow function and have the setTimeout inside myFunction? Thanks for your help